# Using EM clustering with weka in my JAVA code?

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, weka

I apply EM clustering in weka for cluster some points (x, y, z). I wrote EM on my JAVA code:

```
EM em = new EM();
em.setDebug(false);
em.setDisplayModelInOldFormat(false);
em.setMaxIterations(100);
em.setMinStdDev(0.000001);
em.buildClusterer(data_to_use);
```

When it want to build (the last line), it get an error which may it is because of it get only one cluster. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Seriously, you need to tell us the error message if you want us to help... also consider using ELKI It's much faster for me, and has more clustering algorithms.

Comment: Sorry for my late replay. The error is: "weka.core.WekaException: weka.clusterers.EM: Not enough training instances (required: 1, provided: 0)!"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do without any aditional options? e.g.

```
    EM clusterer = new EM();
    clusterer.buildClusterer(dataClusterer);
```

Try to use a filter to take away the Class, or else it will consider this as a feature and therefore only generate 1 cluster, you can use:

```
    // generate data for clusterer (w/o class)
    Remove filter = new Remove();
    filter.setAttributeIndices("" + (data.classIndex() + 1));
    try {
        filter.setInputFormat(data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Instances dataClusterer = Filter.useFilter(data, filter);

    // train clusterer
    EM clusterer = new EM();

    // set further options for EM, if necessary...
    // clusterer.setNumClusters(maxNumofClusters); //-1 for n number of clusters
    clusterer.buildClusterer(dataClusterer);
```

An alternative is also to evaluate directly in  weka (create the arff)

cheers

Comment: TNX for your replay. It dose not work for me. I do not know why. I prefer to use "try_catch" instead.